# Change JSON file path and loading from external to internal

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

2 JSON files of this [open source Amazon Alexa skill](https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-space-explorer) are external. How to load them internally?

These are the files:

1. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ddg-skill/apl/styles.json
2. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ddg-skill/apl/layouts.json

I tried changing  `module.exports` [cdn-path.js](https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-space-explorer/blob/master/lambda/custom/helpers/cdn-path.js) to `'../'` and uploaded both JSON files to lambda in a folder called `apl`. It didn't load the files but I can't find an error code in the console.

cdn-path.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ddg-skill/';
```

This is how the external files get loaded in [launch.js](https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-space-explorer/blob/master/lambda/custom/documents/launch.js): **source: `${cdnPath}apl/layouts.json`**

```
const cdnPath = require('../helpers/cdn-path');
[...]
    document: {
      type: 'APL',
      version: '1.0',
      theme: 'dark',
      import: [
        {
          name: 'alexa-styles',
          version: '1.0.0-beta'
        },
        {
          name: 'alexa-layouts',
          version: '1.0.0-beta'
        },
        {
          name: 'layouts',
          version: '1.0.0',
          source: `${cdnPath}apl/layouts.json`
        },
        {
          name: 'styles',
          version: '1.0.0',
          source: `${cdnPath}apl/styles.json`
        }
      ]
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we consider that this is your structure of the code:

```
lambda
  index.js
  apl/
    layout.json
```

Then, from index.js you need to call

```
const data = require('./apl/layout')

console.log(data.layouts.ImageListItem.parameters)
```

Doing so you should be able to load the json file internally from your lambda.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work - everything stays black. `Error: "The target Lambda application returned a failure response".` Unfortunately there are no logs with more details.

Comment: Sorry Tom, missed the '' in the require. Check again with:
const data = require('./apl/layout')

and that should work as I have just tested it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Did you tested it with the complete Alexa sample skill? https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-space-explorer

Comment: No Tom, that is just an example that I created.

The key will be where you have your file(layout) and where you are calling it.

const data = require('./apl/layout') -> change that to go the correct path